# image_tag in rails app isn't displaying correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I have a png saved in my assets/images folder and am trying to display it with

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    image_tag("/assets/images/fleur_de_lis.png", alt: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

however that is not working. The HTML produced by this is

```
<img alt="Example User" class="gravatar" src="/assets/images/fleur_de_lis.png">
```

and the png is definitely there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `image_tag` in the `gravatar_for` method to read as follows:

```rb
image_tag("fleur_de_lis.png", alt: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", class: "gravatar")
```

Using `image_tag` will automatically look for the image in the `assets/images` folder, and so you need not repeat the directories.

See the example [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html).

I hope that works.